# Fórmula en ReportView C# para mostrar las cantidad, ¿que condicion podria poner?

Tags: c#, sql, reportviewer, aplicación-escritorio, reportviewerreporte

nose como escoger el cuadro de texto para ponerlo como referente en (**expresion**)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes, 2. Mayúsculas == gritar, edita la pregunta por favor. 3. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: gracias poco a poco iré aprendiendo

Comment: de preferencia copia tus lineas de lo que tienes aca, yo uso esas expresiones pero no puedo ver tu imagen.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7coL6.png

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/381961/reportviewer-cual-es-el-nombre-que-tiene-este-cuadro-de-texto-para-poder-utiliz                  - espero se entienda mejor