# ReportViewer,¿Cual es el nombre que tiene este cuadro de texto para poder utilizarlo en una condición?

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer, aplicación-escritorio, reportviewerreporte

Alguien que se sepa como veo el nombre de este cuadro de texto para usarlo en una condición en RDLC en reportviewer con c# por favor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Queria ponerle una expresion el cual utilice los datos de ese cuadro que estan alli y solo cuente los que son de la tabla de arriba, por ahora se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer cuadro esta vacio porque nose que codigo utilizar como expresion para que cuente los que se repite segun su categoria, intente poniendo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa expresion esta en otro cuadro donde dice **cantidad Aumento** entonces llame el cuadro de Textbox25 con una condicion pero no lo reconoce, alguna idea porfas?